# Bad request by F5 with using invalid symbols in URL

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, browser, primefaces, get

I have two pages and I am pass parameters from first to second. Link is created dynamically. I understand that using Java instead of XHTML is bad practice, but that is.

```
public static String SELF_ANALYSIS_URL = "/dashboard/IndicatorOlapView.xhtml";

protected org.primefaces.component.link.Link createLink(IndicatorConclusion indicatorConclusion) {
    Link linkIndicatorOlapView = new Link();
    linkIndicatorOlapView.setOnclick("PF('olapQueryDialog').show();");
    linkIndicatorOlapView.setTitle("Показатель");
    linkIndicatorOlapView.setValue(indicatorConclusion.getIndicatorCondition().getObjectName());
    linkIndicatorOlapView.setOutcome(SELF_ANALYSIS_URL);
    Param paramKey = new Param();
    paramKey.setName("indicatorConclusionKey");
    paramKey.setValue(createEncodeParam(indicatorConclusion.getKey()));
    linkIndicatorOlapView.getChildren().add(paramKey);
    return linkIndicatorOlapView;
}
```

IndicatorOlapView.xhtml

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="indicatorConclusionKey"
                 value="#{indicatorOlapViewModel.indicatorConclusionKey}"/>
    <f:viewAction action="#{indicatorOlapViewModel.init}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Parameters contain's invalid url symbols like `[], =`. Second page successfully rendered, but if I press F5 then get a invalid url and `400 Bad Request`. Why a decoding url using for refresh? Why browser show decoding url?

The link on first page to second page: `http://localhost:8080/dashboard/IndicatorOlapView.xhtml?indicatorConclusionKey=*coordinates%253D%255B%255B%25D0%25A4%25D0%259B%255D%255DminValue%253D0.0maxValue%253D100.0`

URL from address bar on second page: `http://localhost:8080/dashboard/IndicatorOlapView.xhtml?indicatorConclusionKey=*coordinates=[[%D0%A4%D0%9B]]minValue=0.0maxValue=100.0`

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to do and how. Please create an [mcve]. And according to your tags, it works when **not** using utf-8, correct?

Comment: Encoding isn't a problem. A invalid symbols in url is the problem, though url with encode params is valid. When I not using utf-8, then problem same. Remove utf-8 from tags.

Comment: tried different browsers?

Comment: Yes, I tried firefox and chrome.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I use primefaces `p:link`, but probably this is same. Explain me please why on first page I see correct link with encoding invalid symbols (thank's `p:link`), but address bar of second page contains decoding url? Browser decode link automatically? I understand correctly that browser get link by F5 from cache? Decoding or encoding url stored in cache?

Comment: _" Decoding or encoding url stored in cache?"_ no idea, check the http request and response codes in your browser developer tool. Maybe if you create an [mcve] like requested in the first comment, someone (not necessarily me) can easily try to reproduce (or not) or see the real error